# Call data using buttons created from looped array

Tags: javascript, php

Hope the tittle fits my question.

I made a loop to display data from table and it is showed as buttons.

```
<?php
$a=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)){
    $ID = $row['id'];
    $name[] = $row['names'];
    echo "<button name=\"btn$ID\" class='btnName' onClick='showForm()'>$name[$a]</button>";
    $a++;
}

<div id="result" style="display: none;">
    //name from clicked buttons should be displayed here
</div>
?>
```

And here is the function:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function showForm(){
        document.getElementById('result').style.display="block";
    }
</script>
```

The 'id' field is only an incremented field.
If I click the button, I want to display the name I click from one of those buttons in the result div.

How do I call it?

Comment: **Don't** use the **deprecated and insecure** `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: You could pass the name as an argument to the function do do whatever it is you are trying to do with the button name

Comment: You want to show name attribute or the name that you have fetched from database?

Comment: @KamalPaliwal I want to show the name i fetched from there.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks. I'll fix it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your function to be like this

```
 function showForm(elem){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('result').style.display="block";
}
```

and call it so

```
onClick='showForm(this)'
```

Comment: it works! but if i put some codes like php to the result div, it only shows the name and nothing else. What should i change or add to the function?

Comment: What do you want to show exactly ? This function takes every thing in the button and puts it in the result div

Comment: sorry for late respond.
I made another div inside the result div like. So it's like a modal. The code you provided works great to call the name from database but doesn't show anything else . I wonder why?

Comment: Forgive my misunderstanding. It actually works. I only need to change a bit when I put it to my real code. Marked as answer :)

Comment: You can put everything you want as Html in one div which has class or id like(<div id="myData"> your data</div>) and you can take this data from this div to another by calling a function like yours to get that innerHtml to another div . I think it would be easier if you used Jquery.

Comment: Will try it soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly but if I did, try the function below.

```
function showForm(ev) {
  // Or if you want to get the text of the button change it to ev.target.innerText
  const name = ev.target.getAttribute("name"); 

  const result = document.getElementById('result');

  result.innerText = name;
  result.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you. What I meant was I want to get the name i fetched from my database. For example, If I click button "John", it shows "John" in the result div.

But I'll try your function first soon.

Comment: It doesn't work for name constrain and result.innerText lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that you can give it a try and see how this works for you:

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)){
    echo "<button name=\"btn{$row['id']}\" class='btnName' onClick=\"showForm('{$row['name']}')\">{$row['names']}</button>";
}
?>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
function showForm(name) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerText = name;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This would hide all the buttons since you're putting them in a div that has `display: none;`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson You are right. Clicking a hidden button can be problematic and not quite straightforward for the average user. :) 
Edited the answer

Comment: :-) However, this doesn't actually answer the OP's question. The OP doesn't want all the buttons in the div. The OP only wants to show the name of the clicked button in that div.

Comment: Danke @MagnusEriksson! Let's see if this version is closer to the OP vision.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to this:

```
echo '<button name="btn'.$ID.'" class="btnName" onClick="showForm()" data-name="'.$name[$a].'">'.$name[$a].'</button>';
```

And change your JS to this:

```
function showForm(e) {
  var name = e.target.getAttribute("data-name");
  var result = document.getElementById('result');

  result.innerText = name;
  result.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clearly your code should be

```
<?php
 $a=0;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($execute)){
  $ID = $row['id'];
  $name[] = $row['names'];
  echo "<button name='btn{$ID}' class='btnName' onClick=showForm('{$name[$a]}')>{$name[$a]}.    </button>";
  $a++;
 }
?>

<div id="result" style="display: none;">
</div>


<script type="application/javascript">
 function showForm(value){
    let div = document.getElementById('result');
    div.style.display="block";
    div.innerText = value;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript part

```js
function showForm() {    
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('btnName')
  for(var i = 0; i< x.length; i++){
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
    result.innerHTML = e.target.getAttribute("name")
    })
  }
}
showForm()
```

```html
<button name="Button1" class='btnName'>Button1</button>
<button name="Button2" class='btnName'>Button2</button>
<button name="Button3" class='btnName'>Button3</button>
<button name="Button4" class='btnName'>Button4</button>

<div id="result" ></div>
```